# Changing 'modified' timestamps of a file that has been randomly selected in a batch file? WIN7

Tags: batch-file, random

Hey all ive been having abit of fun creating a .bat file to randomly select a file in this case .jpg files, which are then being moved to a location where they will be displayed on a TV.

The tv grabs the newest image from the random photos that get moved.

my question is how do i interoperate the " thouch " commaned into my current existing code?

```
@echo off
:LOOP
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd C:\Users\bruce\Desktop\Test
set n=0
for %%f in (*.*) do (
   set /A n+=1
   set "file[!n!]=%%f"
)
set /A "rand=(n*%random%)/32768+1"
copy "!file[%rand%]!" \\server\TV\NoticeBoard
timeout /t 50
goto :LOOP
```

Comment: copy in the msdos 6.22 help file tells you how. Changing the time and date of a file

If you want to assign the current time and date to a file without modifying
the file, use a command in the following format. The commas indicate the
omission of the destination parameter.

    copy /b source+,,
                                      ♦

Answer (score 0):

```
....
copy /b "!file[%rand%]!"+,,
copy "!file[%rand%]!" \\server\TV\NoticeBoard
....
```